# Finding total number of vertices of a polygon

Tags: permutations, combinations

A polygon has 20 sides .

Then , find total number of triangles using vertices of polygon but not the sides of polygon. Ans is 800.

I used Pnc concept here .

Out of 20 vertices , I select 3 vertices to make a triangle.

$20C_3$ , then I subtract 16 *20.

Why 16? Since every 4 vertices of a polygon can make triangles with 2 sides. That gives us triangle which have one side of a polygon .

I am not getting how to go further than this .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number the vertices 1 through 20.

For the moment, assume that the order in which the vertices are selected matters.

Suppose the first vertex is #1. Then, if the second vertex is #3, there are 15 possible triangles, as the remaining vertex cannot be vertex 20, 1, 2, 3, or 4. Similarly, if the second vertex is #19, there are 15 possible triangles. For any other second vertex (#4 through #18), there are 14 possible triangles, because #20, #2, and the two vertices on either side of the second vertex are ineligible. So, all in all 15 + 15 + 15 * 14 = 240.

Since the first vertex can be any one of the 20, there are 20 * 240 = 4800 possible permutations.

But, order does not matter, so we must divide by $3!=6$ and $4800 / 6 =800$.

Answer (score 2):

You count all triangles and subtract those with *exactly* one polygon edge. You also need to subtract those with *two* such edges.